# How to get python exception traceback in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I have a function which should handle all errors:

```
def err(e):
    import traceback
    message = traceback.print_exc()
    print(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        1/0 # just sample
    except Exception as e:
        err(e)
```

But it returns a short error like so:

`integer division or modulo by zero`

But I need more details (`traceback`) to check errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the exception to your function so why use `traceback`, you've got `e` there; just grab `e.__traceback__` if you need the traceback:

```
import traceback

def err(e):   
    tb = e.__traceback__
    # print traceback
    traceback.print_tb(tb)
```

For an option that doesn't depend on dunders, you could use `sys.exc_info` and keep the traceback:

```
import traceback, sys

def err(e):
    *_, tb = sys.exc_info()    
    # print traceback
    traceback.print_tb(tb)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. how to print traceback?

Comment: for that you should use the `traceback` module; specifically `traceback.print_tb(tb)` would do.

Answer (score 0):

According to the python documentation:

> traceback.print_exc([limit[, file]])
>
> ```
> This is a shorthand for print_exception(sys.exc_type, sys.exc_value, sys.exc_traceback, limit, file). (In fact, it uses
> ```
>
> sys.exc_info() to retrieve the same information in a thread-safe way
>   instead of using the deprecated variables.)

What you're essentially doing is just printing out the error message that is being produced by 1/0

If you want to print out a personalized error message you could do the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        1/0 # just sample
    except Exception as e:
        print 'This is the error I am expecting'
```